# Establish an inequality between the two numbers: $5^{44}$ and $4^{53}$

Tags: inequality

Establish an inequality between the two numbers: $5^{44}$ and $4^{53}$. Also, due to some confusion, we can't use a calculator.

I tried to solve this question for quite some time but was unable to do so.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with $5^3 = 125 \lt 128 = 2^7$:

$$5^{44} = 5^2 \cdot (5^3)^{14} \lt 25 \cdot (2^7)^{14} = 25 \cdot 2^{98} \lt 32 \cdot 2^{98} = 2^{103} = 2 \cdot 4^{51} \lt 4^{53}$$

Comment: yes, good work ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can't use calculators, but you can use the fact that $\log_{10}2\approx0.3$ and $\log_{10}5\approx0.7$.

Since $0.7\cdot44=30.8$ and $0.6\cdot53=31.8$ we have a first estimate.

Going a bit further, we remember that $\log_{10}2>0.3$ and so $\log_{10}5<0.7$; so the previous inequality is enough to conclude.

How to establish the first estimate? Since $1000<1024=2^{10}$, we have that $3=\log_{10}1000<\log_{10} 2^{10}=10\log_{10}2$.

Answer (score 0):

May be, we could consider $$A=\frac{4^{53}}{5^{44}}=\left(\frac45 \right)^{44}\times 4^9$$ Taking logarithms $$\log(A)=44\log\left(\frac45 \right)+9 \log(4)$$ Now using the very fast converging expansion $$\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)=2 x+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{5}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ and using $x=-\frac 19$, this gives as an approximation $$\log(A)\approx -\frac{2898808}{295245}+9\log(4)\approx 2.65834 $$ which is  positive. So $A>1$.

**Edit**

Particularly pleased by @igael's "nice" comments, let me rephrase. The very simple approximation  $$\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x} \right)\approx 2 x$$ is  good for the range $-\frac 12 \leq x \leq \frac 12$ (over this range, the relative error is less than $10$%). So, restarting from $$\log(A)=44\log\left(\frac45 \right)+9 \log(4)=44\log\left(\frac45 \right)+18 \log(2)$$
$$\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\frac 45\implies x=-\frac 19\implies \log\left(\frac45 \right)\approx -\frac 29$$ $$\frac{1+x}{1-x}=2\implies x=\frac 13\implies \log\left(2 \right)\approx \frac 23$$ So $$\log(A)\approx -44\times\frac 29+18\times\frac23=\frac{20}{9}\approx 2.22$$ while the exact value would be $\log(A)\approx 2.66$.

Making the problem more general, for which value of $k$ will  $$B=\frac{4^{44+k}}{5^{44}}>1\implies \log(B)>0$$ Using the same, we end with $$\log(B)\approx -44\times\frac 29+2k\times\frac23=\frac{4}{9} (3 k-22)>0$$ which makes $k>7$.

Comment: hi fdp, how do you compute log without a calculator ?

Comment: @igael. I gave the formula which accurate even using a single term. Try it.

Comment: you need still a calculator. Learn from the above answer. I wonder how people get 75 K ; are you here since 20 years ?

Comment: @igael. Do you need a calculator for $2 \times \frac 19$ ?